# Google Big Query - Date-Partitioned Tables with Eventual Data

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

Our use case for BigQuery is a little unique. I want to start using [Date-Partitioned Tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables) but our data is very much eventual. It doesn't get inserted when it occurs, but eventually when it's provided to the server. At times this can be days or even months before any data is inserted. Thus, the _PARTITION_LOAD_TIME attribute is useless to us.

My question is there a way I can specify the column that would act like the _PARTITION_LOAD_TIME argument and still have the benefits of a Date-Partitioned table? If I could emulate this manually and have BigQuery update accordingly, then I can start using Date-Partitioned tables.

Anyone have a good solution here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need create your own column.
_PARTITIONTIME pseudo column still will work for you!
The only what you will need to do is insert/load respective data batch into respective partition by referencing not just table name but rather table with partition decorator - like yourtable$20160718
This way you can load data into partition that it belong to

Comment: Perfect, since I'm already doing this splitting up my tables. I just have to change how I reference it.  :)

Comment: What about potentially having a massive table and then using a column to separate it into a Day-Partitioned table? Is this possible, or is it best to create the individual tables and then convert to a date-time table?

Comment: If you already have dated(with YYYMMDD suffix) tables  - i would recommend converting them into partitioned tables  - see details in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#converting_dated_tables_into_a_partitioned_table

Comment: I'm trying to, but without a prefix it's complaining. IE, I just named them the date and that was it, but bq partition thinks it should be like nameDATE.

Any advice?  ;)

Comment: i haven't tried converting tables named as YYYYMMDD (w/o prefix). but as workaround you can copy your original tables into new tables with some prefix and then do conversion. note: copy is free so should be reasonable workaround. but it is always option that there is a better way :o)